# Dúvidas ao retornar dados de uma API para o html?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

O problema é que ao clicar no botão converter ele consome a API E mostra a cotação correta no debug e console.
Porém na hora de passar o valor `moedaBVal = cotaçao * moedaAVal` ele passa como `moedaBVal = undefined` ou `NaN`.
Qual pode ser o problema neste caso?
Segue o código:

```js
        class Converter {
            converter() {
                let moedaA = "USD";
                let moedaB = "BRL";
                /* let moedaBVal = 0; */
                let moedaAVal = document.getElementById("inputUSDBRL").value;
                let de_para = moedaA + "_" + moedaB;
                let url = `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${de_para}&compact=ultra&apiKey=234428564665e4c14ce2`;
                fetch(url).then(res=>{return res.json()}).then(json=>{
                    let cotacao = json;
                    let moedaBVal = cotacao * moedaAVal;
                    

                });
                
                
            }
        }
        class Controller {
            constructor() {
                this.converter = new Converter();
            }
            aoClicarConverter() {
                let converter = this.converter.converter();


                let div = `<h5>${converter}</h5>`;

                document.getElementById("resultadoUSDBRL").innerHTML = div;
            }
            domInputDolarEmReais() {
                let moedaA = "USD"
                let moedaB = "BRL"
                let div = document.getElementById("titlleConversorUSDBRL")
                div.innerHTML = moedaA + " Para " + moedaB


            }
        }
        let controller = new Controller;
```

```html
<body onload="controller.domInputDolarEmReais()">
    <h5 id="titlleConversorUSDBRL"></h5>
    <input type="number" placeholder="USD" id="inputUSDBRL">
    <button onclick="controller.aoClicarConverter()">Converter</button>
    <div id="resultadoUSDBRL"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Você terá que tratar a chamada da api. Na função. Com async, e promisse. Vou ver se consigo exemplo e posto.

Comment: Se possível, altere o título da pergunta para algo mais descritivo, lembre-se de quando você pesquisa no Google e encontra titulos que são "exatamente o que você precisa". Tente prover o mesmo sentimento quando alguém encontrar sua pergunta também :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, existem 2 problemas, o primeiro é que para ler o retorno da cotação (na variavel json), você precisa fazer "cotacao.USD_BRL" para acessar o resultado.

O segundo é que o código é assincrono, quando você chamar this.converter.converter()" ele não vai esperar o retorno, por isso não vai aparecer o resultado na tela mesmo como este ajuste.

Para funcionar, as funções "aoClicarConverter" e "converter" teriam que ter os seguintes ajustes:

```
<script>
    class Converter {
        converter() {
            let moedaA = "USD";
            let moedaB = "BRL";
            /* let moedaBVal = 0; */
            let moedaAVal = document.getElementById("inputUSDBRL").value;
            let de_para = moedaA + "_" + moedaB;
            let url = `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${de_para}&compact=ultra&apiKey=234428564665e4c14ce2`;
            fetch(url).then(res=>{return res.json()}).then(json=>{
                let cotacao = json;
                
                let moedaBVal = cotacao.USD_BRL * moedaAVal;
                let div = '<h5>' + moedaBVal + '</h5>';
                document.getElementById("resultadoUSDBRL").innerHTML = div;

            });
            
            
        }
    }
    class Controller {
        constructor() {
            this.converter = new Converter();
        }
        aoClicarConverter() {
            let converter = this.converter.converter();

        }
        domInputDolarEmReais() {
            let moedaA = "USD"
            let moedaB = "BRL"
            let div = document.getElementById("titlleConversorUSDBRL")
            div.innerHTML = moedaA + " Para " + moedaB


        }
    }
    let controller = new Controller;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, para manter o código padrão, você deve usar async e promise para a chamada que mostra o resultado no html, "espere" a api funcionar primeiro e só depois de ter o resultado ela apresentar na tela.

```js
class Converter {
    converter() {
        let moedaA = "USD";
        let moedaB = "BRL";
        let moedaAVal = document.getElementById("inputUSDBRL").value;
        let moedaBVal = 0;
        let de_para = moedaA + "_" + moedaB;
        let url = `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${de_para}&compact=ultra&apiKey=234428564665e4c14ce2`;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(url)
            .then(res=>{
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(json=>{
                resolve(
                    (parseFloat(moedaAVal) * json[de_para]).toFixed(2)
                    );
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            })
        })
    }
}
class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.converter = new Converter();
    }
    async aoClicarConverter() {
        let converter = await this.converter.converter();
        document.getElementById("resultadoUSDBRL").innerHTML = converter;
    }
    domInputDolarEmReais() {
        let moedaA = "USD"
        let moedaB = "BRL"
        let div = document.getElementById("titlleConversorUSDBRL")
        div.innerHTML = moedaA + " Para " + moedaB


    }
}
let controller = new Controller;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="controller.domInputDolarEmReais()">
        <h5 id="titlleConversorUSDBRL"></h5>
        <input type="number" placeholder="USD" id="inputUSDBRL">
        <button onclick="controller.aoClicarConverter()">Converter</button>
        <div id="resultadoUSDBRL"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Explicando o código:

Nesse trecho:

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  // é utilizado um promise, onde o resolve espera o cálculo ser feito, para assim retornar o return res.json();
        fetch(url)
        .then(res=>{
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(json=>{
            resolve(
                (parseFloat(moedaAVal) * json[de_para]).toFixed(2)
                );
        })
        .catch(err => { // no caso de erro, ele retornao erro.
            reject(err);
        })


async aoClicarConverter() { // aqui utiliza-se um async, onde só irá preencher o converter após a api retornar ok. (resolve do promise).
            let converter = await this.converter.converter();
```

Estude mais sobre esses comandos, dica:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRJhc6vXyK4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0sNAXE1ozo